# Dual boot UEFI Windows10/Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

According to system settings I'm working on a Windows 10 BIOS UEFI, not Legacy. If I try to install Ubuntu as UEFI, in case I prepartition disk 0 an error pops up:

> This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may be existing operating systems already installed using "BIOS compatibility mode". If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating systems later.

If I don't prepartition, I don't get the install alongside Windows option, what am I missing?

This is my `sudo parted -l` output:

```
Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B  
Partition Table: gpt  
Disk Flags:   
Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                          Flags  
1      1049kB  135MB  134MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres  
2      135MB   674GB  674GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata  
Model: SCSI DISK (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0GB   
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
Partition Table: gpt  

Disk Flags:   
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags  
1      1049kB  16.0GB  16.0GB  fat32        Microsoft Basic Data  msftdata

There is no trace of Disk1, but I have no problem in booting Windows, whose OS is installed in Disk1. As for `fdisk -l` :  

Disk /dev/loop0: 1.3 GiB, 1425731584 bytes, 2784632 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 70EE78E8-75FE-442A-B477-A13CE5E2ED24  

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type  
/dev/sda1    2048     264191     262144   128M Microsoft reserved  
/dev/sda2  264192 1317378047 1317113856 628.1G Microsoft basic data  
Disk /dev/sdb: 14.9 GiB, 15955173376 bytes, 31162448 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disklabel type: gpt  
Disk identifier: 4CB04652-18BC-471A-B3F4-33CC33844705  
Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type  
/dev/sdb1   2048 31162414 31160367 14.9G Microsoft basic data
```

This is my Windows Disk Manager partition scheme.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

This is my System Information.

[image]

Comment: I don't see an EFI partition, are you sure Win10 is in EFI mode? if you upgraded from Win7, it may be in legacy mode.

Comment: The laptop is brand new, iwill edit the post immediately with disk manager scheme. Im trying to use the non allocated memory in disk 0

Comment: It is called free space not memory, memory is something different. Ok the EFI partition is on the second internal drive not the first. This is likely the cause of the error. you should be ok with installing in EFI mode.

Comment: so you think i should force the installation? Sorry you're right free space!

Comment: yes, it should find the EFI partition when you tell it to continue. Normally computers are setup to boot from the first internal drive, So the check for BIOS OS's might be confused because is setup to boot from the second. It might be best to manually partition to insure that it sets up correctly

Comment: I think grub only wants to install to ESP - efi system partition on drive seen as sda. Either switch drives, or add an ESP onto sda drive.UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation  But your partitioning is not typical of a new Dell. And while Windows is booting UEFI mode, it does not have the standard extra partitions that Windows prefers.

Comment: @oldfred - he has the recovery partitions. they are just at the end instead of the beginning. Yes, his set up is very odd. Perhaps the vendor upgraded an older version.

Comment: guys I think it worked!!! but even running boot repair i can't see a Windows option, any guess?